# Characters in texttt

Tags: typewriter

[This page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/texttt.htm) states, falsely as far as I can tell, that the code

```
\texttt{\alpha in texttt mode }\alpha
```

results in this appearing in the document:

```
\alpha in texttt mode
```

followed by the letter alpha in math mode.

In fact I get this:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

How do I include a backslash or a tilde or a brace or any of many other characters that are not letters within texttt?

Comment: What you want is a verbatim presentation, which uses `\ttshape` and includes non-alphanumeric characters.  The in-line form is `\verb|...|` where the "wrappers" should be a character not in the verbatim string.  (`+` is also often used.)  The display environment `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` is also available.

Comment: `\texttt{\textbackslash{}alpha in texttt mode }$\alpha$`

Comment: Indeed, the site you link contains a lot of nonsense...

Comment: Possibly the inline version of "verbatim" is all that I needed. I hadn't realized that it has an inline version.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I recommend using `listings` package and define your style in which you use `literate` to define how special characters are handled. Check pages 51-52 of `listings` package documentation (v1.8d)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{verbatim}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, % font style and size
    literate=
    *{\\}{{\textbackslash{}}}{1}, % \
}
\lstset{style=verbatim}

\begin{document}
    
    \lstinline|\alpha in texttt mode|
    
    $\alpha$
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a true alpha in a typewriter font, use text fonts and text mode. Here's a simple solution using the babel support for the Greek language and exploiting the fact, that the Greek letter alpha is encoded as 'a':

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\texttt{{\selectlanguage{greek}a} in text mode}
\end{document}
```

The ouput is

[image: ouput of the LaTeX snippet above, showing a typewriter alpha in text mode]

Comment: I didn't have any interest at all in getting a true alpha in typewriter font. That's not what my question is about. I do want to get a backslash and a tilde and various other characters found on the standard qwerty keyboard that texttt cannot normally handle.

Comment: Ah ... the answer to your comment is `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}`, or, for really short inserts, `\verb:`...`:`. All this is standard LaTeX without any packages, packages like `fancyverb` add a lot more bells and whistles to that.

Comment: But `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` does not serve here, and that is why I asked. I thought that was obvious.